# grunt error while lifting server

Tags: sails.js

This is the logging output when lifting the server:

```
verbose: logger hook loaded successfully.
verbose: request hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Loading the app's models and any custom adapters...
verbose: Loading app models...
verbose: Loading app adapters...
verbose: Overriding ejs engine config with ejslocals to implement layout support...
verbose: views hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Loading blueprint middleware...
verbose: blueprints hook loaded successfully.
verbose: responses hook loaded successfully.
verbose: controllers hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Loading policy modules from app...
verbose: Finished loading policy middleware logic.
verbose: policies hook loaded successfully.
verbose: services hook loaded successfully.
verbose: csrf hook loaded successfully.
verbose: cors hook loaded successfully.
  i18n:debug will use /src/config/locales/en.json +0ms
  i18n:debug read /src/config/locales/en.json for locale: en +4ms
  i18n:debug will use /src/config/locales/es.json +2ms
  i18n:debug read /src/config/locales/es.json for locale: es +0ms
  i18n:debug will use /src/config/locales/fr.json +1ms
  i18n:debug read /src/config/locales/fr.json for locale: fr +0ms
  i18n:debug will use /src/config/locales/de.json +1ms
  i18n:debug read /src/config/locales/de.json for locale: de +0ms
verbose: i18n hook loaded successfully.
verbose: session hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Loading app Gruntfile...
verbose: Tracking new grunt child process...
verbose: grunt hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Setting default Express view engine to ejs...
verbose: http hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Preparing socket.io...
verbose: sockets hook loaded successfully.
error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

------------------------------------------------------------------------

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.

error: Troubleshooting tips:
error:
error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
error:
error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
error:
error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
error:      e.g., `/src/.tmp` ?
error:
error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
error:      sudo chown -R YOUR_COMPUTER_USER_NAME /src/.tmp

verbose: Starting ORM...
verbose: orm hook loaded successfully.
verbose: pubsub hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Built-in hooks are ready.
verbose: Instantiating registry...
verbose: Loading router...
verbose: Policy-controller bindings complete!
verbose: All hooks were loaded successfully.
verbose: Starting app at /src...
verbose: Running the setup logic in `sails.config.bootstrap(cb)`...
info:
info:                .-..-.
info:
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.12.5             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info:
info: Server lifted in `/src`
```

I don't want `grunt` to run. Following [Concepts > Assets > Disabling Grunt](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets/disabling-grunt), I don't have a `Gruntfile`, I don't have a `tasks/` folder and my `.sailsrc` looks like this:

```json
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },
  "hooks": {
    "grunt": false
  }
}
```

What am I missing?